# Calling a javascript function multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of those:

```
        <div class="enunt">text here</div>
        <div class="ans"><input type="text" id="amount1" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" /></div>
        <div id="slider1" class="slide"></div>
```

The others have the same structure, but the ids differ by their index number. And I need a function to set up the JQuery sliders. What I did is this:

```
            function slider(i) {
                $( '#slider' + i ).slider({
                    value:4,
                    min: 1,
                    max: 7,
                    step: 1,
                    slide: function( event, ui, i ) {
                        $( '#amount' + i ).val( ui.value );
                    }
                });
                $( '#amount' + i ).val( $( '#slider' + i ).slider( "value" ) );
            }
```

And call it like so:

```
for (var i=1; i<6; i++)
    slider(i);
```

This does not work at all. Where is my mistake ? It's my first JQuery app, so please be nice.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Whatever you do, please don't check the error console. That would just make it too easy for us. `:P`

Comment: Chrome's console shows no errors, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Try throwing a console log or `alert` into the slider function - is it actually being called?

Comment: No, it is not. May the order in which you write the elements be the problem ?

Comment: Is your `for` loop above run within `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you assign to `slide` only takes two parameters, it should be

```
        function slider(i) {
            $( '#slider' + i ).slider({
                value:4,
                min: 1,
                max: 7,
                step: 1,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( '#amount' + i ).val( ui.value );
                }
            });
            $( '#amount' + i ).val( $( '#slider' + i ).slider( "value" ) );
        }
```

Also make sure you include jquery ui JS and CSS files

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/Z2aaE/1/

Comment: So, the problem was that I had my 'for' loop into a different `script` tag. Does that make a difference ?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be overcomplicating things slightly there... something like this is probably all you need (I have added loads of comments to the code to try explain what is going on):

```
var amountFields = [],
    selector = '.slide',
    opts = {
      value: 4,
      min: 1,
      max: 7,
      step: 1,
      slide: function(e, ui) {
        var i = ui.handle.closest(selector).data('sliderId');
        amountFields[i].val(ui.value);
      }
    };

// because you have used a '.slide' class 
// name on your sliders, you can use .each() 
// to iterate through them instead of using
// your for loop that assumes there are only 
// ever 5 sliders
$(selector).each(function() {
  // get 'i' from the sliders id attribute
  var i = this.id.replace(/[a-z\-_]/gi, '');

  // initialise slider on the element 
  // and store 'i' within the elements
  // data for easy access in the
  // slide method later
  $(this).slider(opts).data('sliderId', i);

  // DOM querying is a hit on performance 
  // so cache the jQuery object for re-use 
  // in the slide method instead of 
  // re-querying the DOM
  amountFields[i] = amountFields[i] || $('#amount' + i);

  // set the amounts initial value using 
  // the opts object instead
  amountFields[i].val(opts.value);
});
```

Haven't tested this so not 100% there are no errors in the above but something like that should work.

=================================== UPDATE ======================================

Since you thought the above looked more complicated, here is the exact same code without the comments and caching to show you just how simple it actually is:

```
var opts = {
  value: 4,
  min: 1,
  max: 7,
  step: 1,
  slide: function(e, ui) {
    var i = ui.handle.closest('.slide').data('sliderId');
    $('#amount' + i).val(ui.value);
  }
};

$('.slide').each(function() {
  var i = this.id.replace(/[a-z\-_]/gi, '');
  $(this).slider(opts).data('sliderId', i);
  $('#amount' + i).val(opts.value);
});
```

I added in the caching before for performance so without it, it will perform slower but will still work. The `.replace()` bit is getting the slider ID and removing any letters, hyphens or underscores to leave just the number, the bit we need.

Comment: It actually seems a lot more complicated to me. But thank you.

Comment: @MariusCotofana I've added an update to the bottom of my post to show you how simple it really is :)

Answer (score 1):

Pass `i` into your slide function like this:

```
slide: function( event, ui, i ) {
         $( '#amount' + i ).val( ui.value );
       }
```

Comment: Actually... that shouldn't make a difference - `i` is present in the closure, so the function will have access to it. The function really shouldn't take `i`, or it'll be possible for it to slide some other slider's `amount`... At least from my understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a closing brace `}` in your `function slide(i)`.  Otherwise your script worked like a charm for me.

In the future, you should post the error that you got, or that you didn't get an area.  You can check your code for errors from within the **console** of any modern web browser.

Comment: The closing brace is present in the actual code. Maybe the problem is the order in which you write the elements. Can you please tell me you did you write yours ?